# Android: Store SecretKey in KeyStore

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, android-keystore, secret-key

I use a [SecretKey](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html) to encrypt sensitive data in my application. Currently I am storing my SecretKey in Base64 encoded format in DB or SharedPrefs which is not a safe place to store Secret on a rooted phone. Hence, I want to move my SecretKey to [Android KeyStore](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). The problem I am facing is when I try [this sample code](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#UsingAndroidKeyStore) from Google, it expects a PrivateKey instead of SecretKey. I couldn't figure out a way to store my SecretKey in KeyStore and fetch it for later use. I tried this:

```
private static void writeSecretKeyToKeystore(SecretKey secretKey, Context context) {
KeyStore keyStore = null;
try {
  keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
  keyStore.load(null);
  KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);
  keyStore.setKeyEntry("Key", secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey().getEncoded(), null);
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CertificateException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I try above code, it throws an exception `Operation not supported because encoding is unknown`.

Any sample code would be of great help.

Comment: try the following: keyStore.setEntry("Key", secretKeyEntry, null);

Comment: It won't compile, saying `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found 'SecretKeyEntry'; required  'byte[]'`.

Comment: Please change 'setKeyEntry' to 'setEntry'.

Comment: Damn! I changed it to `setEntry` now and I see this exception `java.security.KeyStoreException: Entry must be a PrivateKeyEntry or TrustedCertificateEntry; was SecretKeyEntry: algorithm - AES`

Answer (score 7):

**WRONG**
java.security.KeyStore can store both symmetric and asymmetric keys. You just need to instantiate KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry passing it your SecretKey in the constructor and then use the KeyStore#setEntry method to save it:

```
keyStore.setEntry(
     "key1",
     new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey),
     new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
             .setBlockMode(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
             .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
             .build());
```

To get it back out use:

```
SecretKey keyStoreKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey("key1", null);
```

**UPDATE**
After some research I was surprised to find out, that AndroidKeyStore doesn't support symmetric keys. (see the discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/gbmIRKRbfq8)

Comment: I don't see any method on KeyStore which accepts SecretKeyEntry object. Also, your answer mentions how to get entry, more than how to set entry. Please check my updated question.

Comment: both methods (getEntry and setEntry) deal with the KeyStore.Entry interface (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.Entry.html). KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry implements this interface, so you can use it everywhere that KeyStore.Entry is expected.

Comment: This won't work on API < 23. I am developing an app starting with Lollipop. I use this code keyStore.setEntry( "key1", new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey), new KeyStoreParameter.Builder(context).setEncryptionRequired(true).build()); but it wouldn't work.

Upvoted your answer though.

Comment: I tried API 28, getting SecretKeyEntry from a keystore, returns null. Java SE: no problem.

Comment: SecretKeyEntry certainly works for recent Android versions (API 28), here is an example: https://github.com/fkirc/secure-zip-notes . However, I believe that AndroidKeyStore does not support any symmetric cryptography for API versions below 23.

Comment: Update: For API versions below 23, you can fallback to KeyStore.getInstance("BouncyCastle"). Of course, this does not provide the hardware security capabilities of modern devices.

Answer (score 0):

The work-around would be to encrypt your SecretKey and store it in SharedPreferences. Then store the key to decrypt your key in the Keystore. Here's an implementation using [scytale](https://github.com/yakivmospan/scytale).

```
public static String getBase64EncodedSecretKey(){
    Store store = new Store(context);
    Crypto crypto = new Crypto(Options.TRANSFORMATION_SYMMETRIC);
    SecretKey key = store.getSymmetricKey("key_alias", null);
    String encryptedData = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("myEncryptedSecretKey", "");
    return crypto.decrypt(encryptedData, key);
}

public static void storeKey(String base64EncodedSecretKey){
    Store store = new Store(context);
    if (store.hasKey("key_alias")) {
        store.deleteKey("key_alias");
    }
    SecretKey key = store.generateSymmetricKey("key_alias", null);
    Crypto crypto = new Crypto(Options.TRANSFORMATION_SYMMETRIC);
    String encryptedData = crypto.encrypt(base64EncodedSecretKey, key);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("myEncryptedSecretKey",encryptedData).apply();
}

// Usage:
//store SecretKey
byte[] encodedKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey().getEncoded();
String base64EncodedKey = Base64.encodeToString(encodedKey);
storeKey(base64EncodedKey);

//get SecretKey
String base64EncodedKey = getBase64EncodedSecretKey();
byte[] encodedKey = Base64.decode(base64EncodedKey);
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES");
```